# Using ttkbootstrap in Tkinter - How to customize themes?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

I'm working on a Tkinter-based GUI in Python and came across the ttkbootstrap library, which seems to offer additional theming capabilities for ttk widgets. However, I'm having trouble customizing themes according to my application's design. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or examples on how to use ttkbootstrap to create a customized theme for Tkinter widgets? Any insights or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I am making a hostel management project in core python. I am using tkinter for GUI. Can I use ttkbootstrap for better GUI?

i used tkinter but it missed some features like responsivness etc.

Comment: You can use the built-in [TTK Creator](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes/themecreator/) to create customized theme.

Answer (score 0):

Run `python -m ttkcreator` to create your own theme or you can import a community created theme.

[Bootstrap Docs](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes/themecreator/#create-a-new-theme)